# How do I find the intersection of more than two polynomial curves?

Tags: python, math, polynomials

I have four polynomial (degree 2) functions and I need to find the intersection of these functions. but I do not know is any way to find all intersections in one step. my suggestion is to equalize two functions and find their roots using `numpy.roots`. but I am not sure if is it true or not. what should I do to find the intersections?
my functions are:

```
y = 1.51250 * x + -0.07969 * x^2 + 18.96116
y = 1.54264 * x + -0.05879 * x^2 + 17.47277
y = 1.49669 * x + -0.04627 * x^2 + 17.69008
y = 1.72147 * x + 0.00052 * x^2 + 18.21067
```

I equal two first equations to find their roots, we will have :

```
-0.03014x-0.0209x^2+1.48839=0
```

I used np.roots to find the roots:

```
coeff=[-0.03014,-0.0209,1.48839]
np.roots(coeff)
```

the roots are:

```
[-7.38253508, 6.68910443]
```

but when I put each of these roots in this equation `-0.03014x-0.0209x^2+1.48839=0` the output is not zero! what is the problem?

Comment: _"but I am not sure if is it true or not"_: what is true or not? If all four do indeed have common points, you will have common roots. You could easily try your proposed method and see if it works for four polynomials you know to intersect at a point.

Comment: The problem has one free variable and four constraints, so there is not guaranteed to be any solution. In this case, there is a point around -5 where the four equations are very close, but there is no point where they're exactly equal. [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1.51250+*+x+%2B+-0.07969+*+x%5E2+%2B+18.96116%2C+1.54264+*+x+%2B+-0.05879+*+x%5E2+%2B+17.47277%2C+1.49669+*+x+%2B+-0.04627+*+x%5E2+%2B+17.69008%2C+1.72147+*+x+%2B+0.00052+*+x%5E2+%2B+18.21067+from+-10+to+10). If there is no exact solution, what should the program do?

Comment: I equalize each of these two functions for example 1.51250 * x + -0.07969 * x^2 + 18.96116 = 1.54264 * x + -0.05879 * x^2 + 17.47277 and try to find the root of -0.03014x-0.0209x^2+1.48839 the roots are array([-7.38253508,  6.68910443]) but when I put, for example, x=6.68910443 in the first equation, y is not zero!!

Answer (score 2):

If a single point exists at which all four curves have the same value, then it should be possible to find the intersections of any one of the curves will each of the other three, and of the resulting intersection, you'd pick the one that's common among them all. I can't think of a "one-step" way to do it besides that. As for finding the intersections between each pair of curves, here's how I would do it:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as Poly


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Your functions:
    
#     y = 1.51250 * x + -0.07969 * x^2 + 18.96116
#     y = 1.54264 * x + -0.05879 * x^2 + 17.47277
#     y = 1.49669 * x + -0.04627 * x^2 + 17.69008
#     y = 1.72147 * x + 0.00052 * x^2 + 18.21067

y1 = Poly((18.96116, 1.51250, -0.07969))
y2 = Poly((17.47277, 1.54264, -0.05879))
y3 = Poly((17.69008, 1.49669, -0.04627))
y4 = Poly((18.21067, 1.72147, -0.00052))


# Showing how to find intersections between y1 and y2 only
# you could repeat this for other combinations as you please:
y1_y2_intersections = (y1-y2).roots()

# This returns the two x values at which the functions y1 and y2 have the same value

# Plotting the curves and their intersections:

x = np.arange(-15, 15) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y1(x), label = 'y1') # Plotting y1
ax.plot(x, y2(x), label = 'y2') # Plotting y2

# Plotting the intersection points

for x, y in zip(y1_y2_intersections, y1(y1_y2_intersections)):
    ax.plot(x, y, marker = 'x', color = 'red', linestyle = 'None', label = f'Root ({x:.2f}, {y:.2f})')
    
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't read if this actually answers the question. But. Python is beautiful indeed!

Comment: I think you're right, the question seems to be asking how to find a point at which all FOUR curves intersect, and that point, if it exists, might only be on the complex plane...

Answer (score 0):

You can equalize any two polynomials and solve the resulting quadratic equations.
There is, of course, a solution for any of these equations. Maybe the some (or all) of them are imaginary or complex. Just ignore these solutions if you want to use only real solutions for your intended purpose.

Comment: I equalize each of these two functions for example 1.51250 * x + -0.07969 * x^2 + 18.96116 = 1.54264 * x + -0.05879 * x^2 + 17.47277 and try to find the root of -0.03014x-0.0209x^2+1.48839 the roots are array([-7.38253508,  6.68910443]) but when I put, for example, x=6.68910443 in the first equation, y is not zero!!

Comment: When you set the two functions equal to each other and rearrange to obtain three new coefficients, what you're actually doing is creating a new polynomial representing the difference between the first two polynomials. That new polynomial DOES evaluate to zero at the values of the roots, but the first two polynomials won't.

Comment: If you're trying to find one point at which all four polynomials have the same value - you can't be certain that such a point exists...

Comment: @Vin, yes I put the root in the new polynomial and I expected that to become zero, but it is not equal to zero. what is the problem?

Comment: @david How can you expect that the roots of a polynomial are equal to the roots of an other polynomial? If that where true both polynomials would be identical disregarding a constant factor.

Comment: I mean after equalizing two polynomials, we have a new polynomial that the roots have to make it zero, but it is not equal to zero.

Comment: @david My last attempt to explain why your expectation is wrong: When you are equalizing two polynomials an then you evaluate the roots of the resulting polynomial, you evaluate the roots of the difference of both polynomials (also see comment of Vin of   Nov 14 at 23:29 and the nice graphic in Vin's answer). How can you expect that both polynomials have the them roots as the difference polynomial. In the graphic you can  easily see that the two points of intersection between both curves are not roots of the two individual polynomials. Your expectation is WRONG.

Comment: @Elec1, I said the same thing, these roots should make zero the achieved polynomial of difference between two polynomials. but when I put these roots in the difference it is not zero! I know they are not the root of the two first polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

For equation

```
-0.03014x-0.0209x^2+1.48839=0
```

coefficients should be **in correct order**

```
coeff=[-0.0209, -0.03014,1.48839]
```

and result for

```
np.roots(coeff)
```

is

```
[-9.19068954  7.74858428]
```